# Google Inbox like RecyclerView item open animation

Tags: java, android, material-design, google-inbox

Currently, I'm trying to implement Google Inbox like `RecyclerView` behaivior, and I'm very curious about email opening animation.

My question is: how to do that? I mean, which method they used? Did they use `ItemAnimator.dispatchChangeStarting()` and change it's height to fill parent? Or something another? And if they do, how they make it close with pull gesture while underlying `RecyclerView` elements are slightly visible.

Can anyone help me with pointing to some library, or code snippets/examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean: the recyclerview as a load items, or once an item and pressing load the next screen.

I leave an example of how I charge items in recyclerview and I give an animation

```
public class CreateAnimationView {

private static int contador;
Integer colorFrom = R.color.myAccentColor;
Integer colorTo = Color.RED;

public static AnimatorSet createAnimation(View view) {
    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha",
            0f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(300);
    ObjectAnimator mover = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,
            "translationX", -500f, 0f);
    mover.setDuration(400);
    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha",
            0f, 1f);
    fadeIn.setDuration(300);
    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

    animatorSet.play(mover);
    animatorSet.start();
    return animatorSet;

 }
... more animations methods.
}
```

In your RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    GruposCardView gruposCardView = gruposCardViews.get(position);

    CreateAnimationView.createAnimationRandom(viewHolder.cardView);
   ...}
```

And if not in the recyclerview you can pass a layout and use this animation or create one from this.

```
 public static AnimatorSet createAnimationCollapseXY(View view) {
    ObjectAnimator scaleXOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 1f, 0f).setDuration(400);
    ObjectAnimator scaleXIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 0f, 1f).setDuration(300);
    ObjectAnimator scaleYOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 1f, 0f).setDuration(400);
    ObjectAnimator scaleYIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 0f, 1f).setDuration(300);
    ObjectAnimator rotateClockWise = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0f, 360f).setDuration(400);
    ObjectAnimator rotateCounterClockWise = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0f, -360f).setDuration(400);


    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

    animatorSet.playTogether(scaleXIn, scaleYIn);
    //animatorSet.setStartDelay(1200);
    animatorSet.start();
    return animatorSet;
}
```