# Transition of list item to expand into details like Google Inbox

Tags: android, android-listview, android-transitions

I want my item in `ListView` to expand into a `Fragment` / `Activity` showing the item details.

Here's an example showing the animation - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75404011/inbox-animation.mp4

I looked at [Google Inbox like RecyclerView item open animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625505/google-inbox-like-recyclerview-item-open-animation) but was not able to perceive the essence.

Could anyone give me some pointers on this?

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this libraries will be useful:

- https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview
- https://github.com/klinker41/android-slidingactivity

Download [this apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpr0ykwl07539uq/sliding-activity-sample.apk?dl=0), the animation is similar to inbox.

I do not think this is easy, but these libraries have a lot a code that could be useful for create the animation.